# make nginx ignore site config when its upstream cannot be reached

Tags: nginx

There are multiple site config in my nginx, and when I restart the machine, if one of the sites' upstream cannot be reached, nginx won't start at all, and those healthy site won't start as a result, how to let nginx ignore those invalid sites?

```
http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# nginx-naxsi config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
##

#include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

##
# nginx-passenger config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
##

#passenger_root /usr;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and sites-enabled/example1 is

```
upstream example1 {
    server example1.service.example.com;
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name example1.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://example1/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
}
```

and sites-enabled/example2 is

```
upstream example2 {
    server example2.service.example.com;
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name example2.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://example2/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
}
```

When I restart the machine and at that time example2.service.example.com is down, nginx will not start at all, i.e. even example1.service.example.com is available, nginx will not serve for example1

=====update
Explanation of "is down":
All the subdomains is automatically registered/deregistered on my own dns server, so if the server is down, the dns will respond no such domain when try to resolve it.

Comment: Could you show your config?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen added.

Comment: @AD7six yes, I mean the upstream doesn't resolve, see question update for more details

Comment: I don't think you can force nginx to start with what boils down to bad config. Since you control the DNS, perhaps set it up to return a valid result with nginx using a short resolver cache.

Comment: @AD7six would backup in upstream work around? I mean if I added another host(which will always be resolvable) in the upstream as backup, would  nginx start up when the normal upstream cannot resolve?

Comment: When you tried, did it work ;)?

Comment: @AD7six not work :( , so I guess the only approach is to modify my dns server and returns a cname whenever the queried domain is not exist, right?

Answer (score 20):

Finally I find out the walkaround, resolve the domain insdie location works!

example:

```
server {
    listen 9000;
    server_name example1.example.com;
    location / {
        set $target http://something.service.lab.mu;
        proxy_pass http://$target;
    }
}
```

And nginx won't try to resolve `http://something.service.lab.mu` at start time.

Comment: Did not work for me. When doing `proxy_pass $target;`, I get "502 Bad Gateway", `proxy_pass http://$target` gives me "500 Internal Server Error". That is when Nginx is in fact able to resolve the host.

Comment: With @EmilBurzo's addition, this works.

Comment: it works like this `proxy_pass $target;` (without the `http://` part in `proxy_pass`). See @IStranger answer

Answer (score 16):

For anyone stumbling upon this issue, @cgcgbcbc is correct.

But you also need to add a

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
```

directive above the

```
set $target http://something.service.lab.mu;
```

otherwise you'll get an error in nginx, like:

```
no resolver defined to resolve
```

Answer (score 7):

There are few ways to avoid it:

1. Use static IP, nginx will return 503's if it doesn't respond.
2. Use the resolver directive to point to something that can resolve the host, regardless if it's currently up or not.
3. Use the resolver directive at the location level, if you can't do the above (this will allow Nginx to start):

   ```
    location /some_path {
      resolver    127.0.0.1   valid=30s;   
      # resolver    8.8.8.8     valid=30s;   # or some other DNS
      # resolver    127.0.0.11  valid=30s;   # or Docker's DNS server

      set         $dummy_var  http://some_domain:80;
      proxy_pass  $dummy_var;
    }
   ```